# How to implement Android paging in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, android-architecture-components

I wanted to know how i can implement pagination using Androidx Paging library using Kotlin, if the REST API doesn't return total number of pages nor the total number of results?

I tried to follow many sample examples for Architecture components, but none of them talk about how to implement paging with above constraints.

Any pointers to a article or tutorial will be greatly helpful.

Comment: does your REST API supports paging ?

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi yes. When i call API using pageNumber and maxResults per page as parameters it gives only that many results. However, it only returns items without any other information.

Comment: yes it should return for you the new requested page items and add it to the old items list and you can know the current items for the list size

Comment: It does return some items other then total_count or total_pages information. Most examples from google sample works with API's that return those information too.So I wanted to know how to implement the paging without those extra information and also which dataSource can be used with this.? Thanks for your time

Comment: total_count and total_pages store them of a variables, each time you request a new page increment the total_pages, and from the response get the items size to added it to total_count.

Comment: Thank you @FahadAlotaibi for the pointers. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Given the API behavior you've metioned, i think PageKeyedDataSource is the right match to get previous/next records from the current page (that you know as per your response above).
Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PageKeyedDataSource.html) documentation. Also refer [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@harunwangereka/android-paging-library-with-kotlin-coroutines-b96602e3fae3) with sample implementation, remember to replace android.arch.paging... (deprecated) with androidx.paging... package (jetpack). 
Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for the useful pointers. Will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, My rest API doesnt have before and after properties as part of the JSON response, in that case how to implement PageKeyedDataSource?

Comment: Hi @prakashpun, u need to customize the sample code a bit by modifying loadBefore()/loadAfter() methods by passing current current pagenumber -1 or +1 instead of before/after params in API call here: apiService.fetchPosts(loadSize = params.requestedLoadSize, before = params.key)